# Disable Information/Definition boxes in Anaconda in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda3 in ST3 in Ubuntu 14.04, after that I am facing following issues:

1. Shows definition of in-built functions:

[image: Fig.1]

2. Shows random information after completion of line:

[image: Fig.2]

I want to disable this feature of anaconda but I could not find any solution elsewhere. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 related options you can edit @ [**`Anaconda.sublime-settings`**](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda/blob/master/Anaconda.sublime-settings).

1. `"enable_signatures_tooltip": true,`
2. `"enable_docstrings_tooltip": true,`

Try setting [ either | both ] to `false` to find which combination best suits your preference.

---

---

To edit them:

- Navigate to:

  - Menu / Preferences / Package Settings / Anaconda / Settings - User
- paste the contents of the file linked above
- edit the settings you wish to alter
- save the file

Comment: FYI, I created the `[sublime-anaconda]` tag a little while ago, and have been retagging `[anaconda]` questions as necessary - some use the plugin, some use the Python distribution, and probably some use both, so make sure you know what the question is *really* about. Feel free to retag anything I missed.